# Ajax call not firing from checkbox onClick

Tags: jquery, ajax, checkbox, onclick, onchange

I'm trying to do somthing very simple, to trigger a query on database when checkbox in the form is checked, but when user click on it simple does nothing. I've tryied to onClick or onChange event handles without sucess. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for any suggestion!

```
  <head>
  //I'm using joomla and document.js is loading normaly
  $document->addScript("path/document.js");
  </head>

  <body>
  <form id='avisar' method='post' name='avisar'><div id='risposta'></div><input type='checkbox' name='invia' id='invia' value='yes' />Check it!</form>
  </body>
```

Document.js: EDITED to get variables properly

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
$('#invia').change(function(){

    //variable
    var name = $("#att").val();
    var user = $("#user_id").val();
    var datastr ='name=' + name + '&amp;user=' + user;

    var id = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        // checkbox is checked -> do something
        $.ajax({
        url: "processa_form_avisar.php",
        data: datastr,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
            alert('Updated successful.');
            $('#risposta').fadeIn("slow");
            $('#risposta').html(html);
            $('#risposta').css("background-color","#e1ffc0");
            setTimeout(function() {
            $("#risposta").fadeOut("slow");
            }, 2000);

            }
        });
    } else {
        // checkbox is not checked -> do something different
    }
```

});
});

Answer (score 0):

Use the jQuery change event instead of click...

Comment: thanks Gisli, I did this change: $('#invia').change(function(){ but still nothing :(

Comment: Are you setting the event on document ready? Is the event code being hit at all?

Comment: I edited it now with to set it on document ready, what do you mean is the event code being hit? Sorry for my unexperience..

Comment: I mean, is the event handler being executed? Are you maybe getting an exception within the handler? parseInt($(this).val()) comes to mind. Parsing the value of a checkbox to an integer?

Comment: Sorry... Maybe I should have read your code a little better. Parsing the value of the checkbox would return NaN, but you don't use that value anywhere. However, your html doesn't include and inputs for the name or user id.